# Cannot calculate antiderivative using undefined coefficients

Tags: calculus, integration

Using a simple substitute, I have simplified the function whose antiderivative needs to be calculated to the following form:

$$I=\int{\frac{2x^4-x^3}{x^5+1}dx}$$

Using the method of undefined coefficients, I tried to break this function as following:

$$\frac{2x^4-x^3}{x^5+1} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{Bx+C}{x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1}$$
$$= \frac{A\cdot(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1) + (Bx+C)\cdot(x+1)} {(x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)}$$

This is equivalent to:

$$\begin{align}2x^4-x^3 &= A\cdot(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1) + (Bx+C)\cdot(x+1)\\
&= Ax^4 -Ax^3+Ax^2-Ax+A+Bx^2+Bx+Cx+C\\
&= Ax^4 -Ax^3 +x^2(A+B) + x(-A+B+C) + (A+C)\\
\end{align}$$

whis is equivalent to the following system:

$$\begin{cases}
A=2 \\ 
-A = -1 \implies A=1 \\ 
A+B=0 \\
-A+B+C=0\\
A+C=0
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly the problem is with the coefficient A. This method worked for me so far and I am not sure as to where did I go wrong.

Comment: You have to decompose $\;x^5+1\;$ in a product of linear and/or quadratic factors. It is a horrible outcome and several questions close to this with that quintic in the denominator have been asked lately. Either there's no simplifying trick to deal with that or else nobody has shown it.

Answer (score 2):

You need more coefficients. In general, when doing partial fractions (or what you are calling undefined coefficients), what you put in the numerator needs to be a polynomial of 1 degree less than the denominator. So for you, you need $$\frac{2x^4 - x^3}{(x+1)(x^4 -x^3 + x^2 -x + 1)} = \frac{A}{x+1} + \frac{Bx^3 + Cx^2 + Dx + E}{x^4 -x^3 + x^2 -x + 1}.$$ That is, on top of the 4th degree polynomial, you need a 3rd degree polynomial. Then it will work.

Edit: grammar

Comment: For the decomposition of the rational function this works, for solving the integral I doubt it: the solutions is almost a nightmare.

Comment: But this way the second partial fraction is of the same sort as the one I started with: the numenator is of 1 degree less than the denominator, which this time can't be factored over the real numbers.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yes I agree. This gives no hint as to how to actually find the antiderivative and that much is indeed a nightmare. 

Original poster: I'm not quite sure what you mean. You need a 3rd degree polynomial because on top of the 4th degree polynomial. This way, when you cross multiply, you end up with a 4th degree polynomial on top of a fifth degree polynomial which is exactly what you started with. If you didn't get back exactly what you started with, you wouldn't be able to solve the resulting equations (which is what happened when you tried with only $Bx + C$).

Comment: My mistake, I understood everything.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^3}{x^5+1}=x^3\prod_{k=0}^4\frac1{x-\omega_k}=\sum_{k=0}^4\frac{A_k}{x-\omega_k}$$ where $\omega_k=e^{i\theta_k}=\cos\theta_k+i\sin\theta_k$ and $\theta_k=\frac{2\pi(2k+1)}{10}$. Then
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\omega_k}\frac{x^3(x-\omega_k)}{x^5+1}=\frac00=\lim_{x\rightarrow\omega_k}\frac{x^3+3x^2(x-\omega_k)}{5x^4}=\frac{\omega_k^3}{5\omega_k^4}=-\frac15\omega_k^4=\lim_{x\rightarrow\omega_k}\sum_{j=0}^4\frac{A_k(x-\omega_k)}{x-\omega_j}=\sum_{j=0}^4A_k\delta_{jk}=A_k$$
So now we have $$\int\frac{2x^4-x^3}{x^5+1} dx=\frac25\ln(x^5+1)+\frac15\sum_{k=0}^4\int\frac{\omega_k^4}{x-\omega_k} dx$$ Now,
$$\int\frac{\omega_0^4}{x-\omega_0}dx=\omega_0^4\ln(x-\omega_0)+C_0=\omega_0^4\ln(x-\cos\theta_0-i\sin\theta_0)+C_0=\omega_0^4\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2-2x\cos\theta_0+1}e^{i\text{atan2}(-\sin\theta_0,x-\cos\theta_0)}\right)+C_0=\omega_0^4\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2-2x\cos\theta_0+1}e^{i\tan^{-1}(x-\cos\theta_0)/\sin\theta_0-i\pi/2}\right)+C_0$$ With a little more work,
$$\int\frac{\omega_0^4}{x-\omega_0}dx+\int\frac{\omega_4^4}{x-\omega_4}dx=\cos(4\theta_0)\ln\left(x^2-2x\cos\theta_0+1\right)-2\sin(4\theta_0)\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\cos\theta_0}{\sin\theta_0}\right)+C_{04}=\frac{-\sqrt5-1}4\ln\left(x^2-\frac{\sqrt5+1}2x+1\right)-\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x-\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}\right)+C_{04}$$ and
$$\int\frac{\omega_1^4}{x-\omega_1}dx+\int\frac{\omega_3^4}{x-\omega_3}dx=\cos(4\theta_1)\ln\left(x^2-2x\cos\theta_1+1\right)-2\sin(4\theta_1)\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x-\cos\theta_1}{\sin\theta_1}\right)+C_{13}=\frac{\sqrt5-1}4\ln\left(x^2+\frac{\sqrt5-1}2x+1\right)-\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}\right)+C_{13}$$ and of course
$$\int\frac{\omega_2^4}{x-\omega_2}dx=\int\frac1{x+1}dx=\ln(x+1)+C_2$$ so overall we have
$$\int\frac{2x^4-x^3}{x^5+1}dx=\frac25\ln(x^5+1)+\frac15\ln(x+1)+\frac{-\sqrt5-1}{20}\ln\left(x^2-\frac{\sqrt5+1}2x+1\right)-\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}{10}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x-\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}\right)+\frac{\sqrt5-1}{20}\ln\left(x^2+\frac{\sqrt5-1}2x+1\right)-\frac{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}{10}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{4x+\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt{10+2\sqrt5}}\right)+C$$ I'm too tired to continue. Hopefully others will edit my errors.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, the antiderivative is not the most pleasant to find.

However, writing $$x^5+1=(x-1)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$$ a complete full partial fraction decomposition would lead to $$\frac{2x^4-x^3}{x^5+1}=\frac{1}{(a-1) (b-1) (c-1) (d-1) (x-1)}+\frac{2 a^4-a^3}{(a-1) (a-b) (a-c) (a-d) (x-a)}+\frac{2 b^4-b^3}{(b-1) (b-a) (b-c)
   (b-d) (x-b)}+\frac{2 c^4-c^3}{(c-1) (c-a) (c-b) (c-d) (x-c)}+\frac{2
   d^4-d^3}{(d-1) (d-a) (d-b) (d-c) (x-d)}$$ which is simple to integrate. For sure the problem would be to simplify (by recombination) the logarithms which contains complex numbers as well as the coefficients.

What I suspect is that, by to reals, the result contains three logarithms and two $\tan^{-1}(.)$

However the problem can be a little simplified wrting $$I=\int{\frac{2x^4-x^3}{x^5+1}dx}=\frac 25\int\frac{5x^4}{x^5+1}dx-\int\frac{x^3}{x^5+1}dx$$ $$I=\frac 25 \log(x^5+1)-\int\frac{x^3}{x^5+1}dx$$ and doing the same as before $$\frac{x^3}{x^5+1}=\frac{1}{(a-1) (b-1) (c-1) (d-1) (x-1)}+\frac{a^3}{(a-1) (a-b) (a-c) (a-d) (x-a)}+\frac{b^3}{(b-1) (b-a) (b-c) (b-d)
   (x-b)}+\frac{c^3}{(c-1) (c-a) (c-b) (c-d) (x-c)}+\frac{d^3}{(d-1) (d-a) (d-b)
   (d-c) (x-d)}$$