# Find the integral $\int \frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{(2x-3)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{(2x-3)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}=\frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}(x-1)}=\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}(x-1)}$$

$$\int \frac{1}{x-1}\mathrm dx=\ln|x-1|+c$$
$$\int \frac{1}{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}(x-1)}\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{2x-3}(x-1)}\mathrm dx$$

Substitution $u=2x-3,du=2dx$ gives
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{2x-3}(x-1)}\mathrm dx=\int \frac{1}{u^{6/5}+u^{1/5}}\mathrm du$$

How to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{u^{6/5}+u^{1/5}}\mathrm du$?

Comment: Maybe like 3 times same kind of question asked

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Let $u^{1/5}=v$ so $$\int\frac{du}{u^{6/5}+u^{1/5}}=5\int\frac{v^4}{v^6+v}dv=5\int\frac{v^3}{v^5+1}dv$$
and factorize $v^5+1$ as $$(1 + v)(v^4 - v^3 + v^2 - v + 1).$$

Comment: It seems that the integral gets complicated by using partial fractions, $\frac{v^3}{v^5+1}=\frac{A}{v+1}+\frac{Bv^3+Cv^2+Dv+E}{v^4-v^3+v^2-v+1}$. Is there a way to evaluate this integral without partial fractions?

Answer (score 1):

As @Archis Welankar noted, this integral is familiar. If we let $u=(2x-3)^{\frac15}$, then $2x-3=u^5$, so $dx=\frac52du$. Then
$$\int\frac{2\sqrt[5]{2x-3}-1}{(2x-3)\sqrt[5]{2x-3}+\sqrt[5]{2x-3}}dx=\int\frac{2u-1}{u^6+u}\cdot\frac52u^4du=\frac52\int\frac{2u^4-u^3}{u^5+1}du$$
[I calculated this integral a couple of weeks ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693463/cannot-calculate-antiderivative-using-undefined-coefficients/1694043#1694043). Today I checked that integral by comparing with numerical solution, and it passed verification.